# kendo - mutiselect - loading spinner while rendering

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

I am using kendo multiselect element with some list which have 200+ elements.
All elements are loaded before you can access the multiselect - but it take some time to render these elements in multiselect.
Is there a way to display loading spinner while multiselect element is rendering?
I am  not talking about displaying spinner while it get data from remote - i have all data downloaded and the only problem is that multiselect is rendering too slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

200+ is not a big number that Kendo or the browser should have problems rendering. Are you using big JS objects that you bind to the multiselect? That could be part of an issue.

Played with this fiddle and adding more than 500 elements didn't matter performance-wise:
http://jsfiddle.net/abhinavg/87f3xjr2/

You can add more options in the select:

```
<option>Steven White</option>
```

---

If you have a large number of items in the dropdown, this is what you can do:

- Implement pagination (preferably on backend side)
- Narrow the list using categories or multiple hierarchical dropdowns (eg. Choose Country -> Choose County -> Choose City) - if available
- Make use of autocomplete (don't load the items until the user enters the first 2-3 chars)

---

Anyway, it's best to add a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: it's actually 2000+ elements (sorry) - but it is doesn't matter
i'm asking if it is possible to display some loading spinner while rendering (i don't see any event like 'onRendered' or something https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/multiselect )

Comment: There isn't as this is more like the browser's operation in progress (you could hack it to show a spinner and hide when an element is visible). You will need to implement pagination or some sort of live search so the user can enter some characters (minimum 2-3) to narrow the list. It's not a good idea to add 2k DOM elements at once anyway, you will have serious performance issues on slower computers (check the Performance tab in Developer tools with a 4x slower Processor). Sorry, but there's no real solution and you will need to implement it the right way. I added more info to the answer.